# Maps in fragment crashes in sliding drawer when clicked twice on Maps item

Tags: maps, fragment, sliding, drawer

Maps in fragment crashes in sliding drawer when clicked twice on Maps item

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fine_tech, container, false);
    fragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid crashes I'm using global variable which I declare in `MyApplication` class which extends from `Application` class

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
boolean mapstate = app.isMapstate();
String bvalue = String.valueOf(mapstate);
Log.e("tag1", bvalue);
Fragment fragment = null;

switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new UserProfileScreen();
    app.setMapstate(false);
    String c = String.valueOf(mapstate);
    Log.e("case0", c);
    break;
case 1:
    if(mapstate==false)
    {
        fragment = new MapFineTech();
        app.setMapstate(true);
        String bvalue2 = String.valueOf(mapstate);
        Log.e("tag2", bvalue2);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I have many Fragments from Slidingdrawer.When i have the HomeFragment pressed and it has a map and when i click it again it crashes.How can i avoid it??

Comment: try{
   
   if (fragment != null) {
    
     fragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
             FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.remove(fragment);
             ft.commit();
   }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
    Thread.interrupted();
  super.onPause();